# Rendering cube on top of square having video feed as texture

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I am trying to develop a POC which helps to visualize a 3D object on camera feed. The kind 3D object I have, easily gets rendered using [this](https://github.com/ricardo-rendoncepeda/mtl2opengl) project. And I am referring [Camera Ripple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html) code by Apple for showing camera feed. Both of these are separate objects in the same context. Each of these uses its own shader program. I am confused how to switch from one program to another.

My  `glkview:drawInRect:` method looks like this

```
    - (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(_program);
if (_ripple)
{
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, [_ripple getIndexCount], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}

glUseProgram(_program1);

glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Set View Matrices
[self updateViewMatrices];
glUniformMatrix4fv(_uniforms.uProjectionMatrix, 1, 0, _projectionMatrix1.m);
glUniformMatrix4fv(_uniforms.uModelViewMatrix, 1, 0, _modelViewMatrix1.m);
glUniformMatrix3fv(_uniforms.uNormalMatrix, 1, 0, _normalMatrix1.m);

// Attach Texture
glUniform1i(_uniforms.uTexture, 0);

// Set View Mode
glUniform1i(_uniforms.uMode, self.viewMode.selectedSegmentIndex);

// Enable Attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aVertex);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aNormal);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aTexture);

// Load OBJ Data
glVertexAttribPointer(_attributes.aVertex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, cubeOBJVerts);
glVertexAttribPointer(_attributes.aNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, cubeOBJNormals);
glVertexAttribPointer(_attributes.aTexture, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, cubeOBJTexCoords);

// Load MTL Data
for(int i=0; i<cubeMTLNumMaterials; i++)
{
    glUniform3f(_uniforms.uAmbient, cubeMTLAmbient[i][0], cubeMTLAmbient[i][1], cubeMTLAmbient[i][2]);
    glUniform3f(_uniforms.uDiffuse, cubeMTLDiffuse[i][0], cubeMTLDiffuse[i][1], cubeMTLDiffuse[i][2]);
    glUniform3f(_uniforms.uSpecular, cubeMTLSpecular[i][0], cubeMTLSpecular[i][1], cubeMTLSpecular[i][2]);
    glUniform1f(_uniforms.uExponent, cubeMTLExponent[i]);

    // Draw scene by material group
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, cubeMTLFirst[i], cubeMTLCount[i]);
}

// Disable Attributes
glDisableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aVertex);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aNormal);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aTexture);
}
```

this cause a crash by throwing this error `gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem is reseting everything between the use of both programs. Now my  `glkview:drawInRect:` looks like below,

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(_program);
if (_ripple)
{
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, [_ripple getIndexCount], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    [self resetProgrameOne];
}


glUseProgram(_program1);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Set View Matrices
[self updateViewMatrices];
glUniformMatrix4fv(_uniforms.uProjectionMatrix, 1, 0, _projectionMatrix1.m);
glUniformMatrix4fv(_uniforms.uModelViewMatrix, 1, 0, _modelViewMatrix1.m);
glUniformMatrix3fv(_uniforms.uNormalMatrix, 1, 0, _normalMatrix1.m);


// Attach Texture
glUniform1i(_uniforms.uTexture, 0);

// Set View Mode
glUniform1i(_uniforms.uMode, 1);

// Enable Attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aVertex);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aNormal);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aTexture);

// Load OBJ Data
glVertexAttribPointer(_attributes.aVertex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, table1OBJVerts);
glVertexAttribPointer(_attributes.aNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, table1OBJNormals);
glVertexAttribPointer(_attributes.aTexture, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, table1OBJTexCoords);

// Load MTL Data
for(int i=0; i<table1MTLNumMaterials; i++)
{
    glUniform3f(_uniforms.uAmbient, table1MTLAmbient[i][0], table1MTLAmbient[i][1], table1MTLAmbient[i][2]);
    glUniform3f(_uniforms.uDiffuse, table1MTLDiffuse[i][0], table1MTLDiffuse[i][1], table1MTLDiffuse[i][2]);
    glUniform3f(_uniforms.uSpecular, table1MTLSpecular[i][0], table1MTLSpecular[i][1], table1MTLSpecular[i][2]);
    glUniform1f(_uniforms.uExponent, table1MTLExponent[i]);

    // Draw scene by material group
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, table1MTLFirst[i], table1MTLCount[i]);
}

// Disable Attributes
glDisableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aVertex);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aNormal);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(_attributes.aTexture);
}
```

and `resetProgrameOne` method resets all the buffers and necessary things by deleting buffers and disabling `glDisableVertexAttribArrays`.